# I cannot migrate project from "no organisation" to a newly created one. It says I do not have permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have several projects without organisation which I want to migrate. I followed that guide https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization
When I try to migrate project to my organisation using UI it says:

> You do not have the following required permission to perform this action: "resourcemanager.projects.update"

My user roles on organisation level:

- Billing Account Administrator
- Billing Account Creator
- Billing Account User
- Folder Admin
- Organisation Administrator
- Organisation Policy Administrator
- Organisation Role Administrator
- Owner
- Project Creator
- Project Mover
- Security Centre Admin
- Support Account Administrator

On project level this user has:

- Owner

When I do from CLI
`gcloud beta projects move hidden-project-name --organization MY_ORG_ID`
I get this:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.projects.move) User [greg@***] does not have permission to access projects instance [hidden-project-name] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission

Some details:
`gcloud auth list` shows my user which has permissions
`gcloud projects list` shows available projects correctly

I ran all commands from Cloud Shell.

Any ideas which roles I have to assign to my user?

Comment: The required permissions are in your list of roles. So, that means either you are using a different identity than you think you are, or the identity you are using does not have the required roles. If you can use the CLI so that we can see the command and the error message. **gcloud beta projects move PROJECT_ID --organization ORG_ID** Make sure the CLI is using the correct identity (gcloud auth list).

Comment: I've updated my question. CLI still complains about permissions :(

Comment: What is the result of the `gcloud auth list` ? If it's not the same as the one you have the "owner" role then change it with `gcloud config set account` and try again.

Comment: It is the same. I double checked with Policy analyser that I have proper permissions on both ends(Organisation and Project) for the same user.

Comment: I think you are not using the correct **Project ID**. Make sure you are not using the project name. I will guess that the project ID that you are specifying exists but is owned by another company/individual.

Comment: I'm using a proper id which I took from `gcloud projects list`

Comment: Some detail is being overlooked. Your question lacks enough information to identify the actual problem.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue on my side, migrate project without organisation in another one doesn't work. I have the same account (email) in the project to move and the destination organisation.

Permissions in the destination (organisation):

[image]

Permissions in the resource to move (Firebase project without organisation):

[image]

If I try to migrate from https://console.cloud.google.com, I have this error:

[image]

If I try to migrate from CLI, I have this error:

```
./Documents/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud beta projects move IDPROJECT --organization IDORGA
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.projects.move) User [email@email.com] does not have permission to access projects instance [PROJECT_TO_MOVE_NAME] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission